# How stub a global dependency's new instance method in nodejs with sinon.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Sorry for the confusing title, I have no idea how to better describe it. Let's see the code:

```
var client = require('some-external-lib').createClient('config string');

//constructor
function MyClass(){
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function(a,b){
  client.doWork(a+b);
}

MyClass.prototype.doSomethingElse = function(c,d){
  client.doWork(c*d);
}

module.exports = new MyClass();
```

Test:

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var MyClass = requre('./myclass');
var client = require('some-external-lib').createClient('config string');

describe('doSomething method', function() {
   it('should call client.doWork()',function(){
      var stub = sinon.stub(client,'doWork');
      MyClass.doSomething();
      assert(stub.calledOnce); //not working! returns false
   })
})
```

I could get it working if .createClient('xxx') is called inside each method instead, where I stub client with:

```
var client = require('some-external-lib');

sinon.stub(client, 'createClient').returns({doWork:function(){})
```

But it feels wrong to init the client everytime the method each being called.

Is there a better way to unit test code above?

---

**NEW**: I have created a minimal working demo to demonstrate what I mean: https://github.com/markni/Stackoverflow30825202 (Simply `npm install && npm test`, watch the test fail.) This question seeks a solution make the test pass without changing main code.

Comment: Each test should be able to run in isolation so stubbing it before each test is appropriate and correct. Depending on earlier tests stubbing (changing state) is a very bad idea.

Comment: Your use of `.yield()` suggests that `.doWork()` is async, but the rest of your code (inclusing your test) doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises at the place of test definition. The fact is that in Node.js it is rather difficult to do a dependency injection. While researching it in regard of your answer I came across an interesting [article](http://howtonode.org/testing-private-state-and-mocking-deps) where DI is implemented via a custom `loadmodule` function. It is a rather sophisticated solution, but maybe eventually you will come to it so I think it is worth mentioning. Besides DI it gives a benefit of access to private variables and functions of the tested module.

To solve the direct problem described in your question you can stub the client creation method of the `some-external-lib` module.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
//instantiate some-external-lib
var client = require('some-external-lib');

//stub the function of the client to create a mocked client
sinon.stub(client, 'createClient').returns({doWork:function(){})

//due to singleton nature of modules `require('some-external-lib')` inside
//myClass module will get the same client that you have already stubbed
var MyClass = require('./myclass');//inside this your stubbed version of createClient 
//will be called. 
//It will return a mock instead of a real client
```

However, if your test gets more complicated and the mocked client gets a state you will have to manually take care of resetting the state between different unit tests. Your tests should be independent of the order they are launched in. That is the most important reason to reset everything in `beforeEach` section

Comment: I find it surprising that it is so hard to find concrete examples of something so 'simple'. Thank you for making testing a lot easier for all of us.

Answer (score 1):

You can use beforeEach() and afterEach() hooks to stub global dependency.

```
var sinon = require('sinon');
var MyClass = requre('./myclass');
var client = require('some-external-lib').createClient('config string');

describe('doSomething method', function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        // Init global scope here
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();           
    });


   it('should call client.doWork()',function(){
      var stub = sinon.stub(client,'doWork').yield();
      MyClass.doSomething();
      assert(stub.calledOnce); //not working! returns false
   })
   afterEach(function () {
        // Clean up global scope here
        sandbox.restore();
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is here: `var stub = sinon.stub(client,'doWork').yield();`

`yield` doesn't return a stub.  In addition, `yield` expects the stub to already have been called with a callback argument.

Otherwise, I think you're 95% of the way there.  Instead of re-initializing for every test, you could simply remove the stub:

```
describe('doSomething method', function() {
   it('should call client.doWork()',function(){
      var stub = sinon.stub(client,'doWork');
      MyClass.doSomething();
      assert(stub.calledOnce);
      stub.restore();
   })
})
```

BTW, another poster suggested using Sinon sandboxes, which is a convenient way to automatically remove stubs.

Comment: I just removed the `yield()` so it won't confuse you guys.  And without it the callCount is still 0.  The problem here is sinon can't stub `require('xxx').createClient('config')` (Most likely it's stubbed to a totally different instance than the one being called).  My other test works just fine when stub `require('yyy')` . Just this library with a `createClient()` method is breaking it.

Comment: @MarkNi This is quite expected since the module by `require` is actually a singleton loaded first time it was called. So in your test you can stub the `createClient()` before you require `myClass` (where it will be required AND client will be created) However this approach will not allow you to reset your stub before each test which is a good practice as already stated here

Comment: @KirillSlatin Ah, so I have to stub to `createClient()` instead of `doWork()`  and let it return a mock client. If you can put it in a answer, I can mark it as correct, thanks!